# ocelot always launch with port 5000

Tags: asp.net-core, api-gateway, ocelot

I'm trying to deploy my ocelot gateway server.

I had typed `UseUrls("http://localhost:6000")` and I saw the server launched with 6000 port. In order to I tried to change port, after delete *UseUrls* syntax, I modified *ocelot.json* file like below

```
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:6000"
  }
```

However, my server launched with 5000 port again.

First, I guess there were some error in json file .So I modified a rerouting APIs in same json file. But It worked well. That is, json file is working well.

Second, I moved *GlobalConfiguration* to top of the file and It didn't work as well. But rerouting worked well.

Also I tried to below also

**appsettings.json**

```
"urls" : "http://localhost:6000"
```

This didn't work either.

Is there anyone to help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Does this blogs useful to you ?](https://www.philbroderick.net/blog/configuring-routes-for-ocelot-api-gateway-(part-2))

Comment: From your brief description, I'm not sure if you're using AddOcelot.

Comment: @JasonPan I think If I didn't use AddOcelot, ReRouting wouldn't worked as well. But only ReRouting worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using the below JSON (**Kestral** key in JSON file). I guess it is not a proper solution, but for other people who are in the same situation:

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:6000"
      }
    }
  },
```