# Why is the ocelot API gateway when published runs on localhost:5000 instead of the base URL?

Tags: asp.net, .net, api-gateway, ocelot

I have an API gateway using ocelot (latest), when run in Visual Studio, it runs on the base UR, but when I publish it into an exe it runs on localhost:5000.

This is my launchsettings.json:

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57930",
      "sslPort": 44329
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "APIGateway": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:2080",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "APIGateway Production": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:2080", // Change this to your production port
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production" // Change this to "Production"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following is my program.cs:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();


builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().SetIsOriginAllowed((hosts) => true));
});


builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");

app.MapControllers();

await app.UseOcelot();

app.Run();
```

Ocelot.json:

```json
{
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:2080", // Api Gateway Port
    "RequestIdKey": "OcRequestId",
    "AdministrationPath": "/administration"
  },
  "Routes": [
    ....Some Routes....
  ]
}
```

I tried this approach it works, but it is not based on the latest guidelines:
[Ocelot Api Gateway](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-api-gateway-using-ocelot-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705620/ocelot-always-launch-with-port-5000